# Print Java's Package Hierarchy with Ant

Tags: java, ant

I want to list all my java packages with ant's "echo". I mean, for example, I have this package hierarchy:

1. Folder1

   - Package1
   - Package2
2. Folder2

   - Package1
   - Package2

The ant file must show something like this with echo's task:

- Folder1.Package1
- Folder1.Package2
- Folder2.Package1
- Folder2.Package2

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us what you ave tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example target showing how this is possible. Note that you might need to change the `dirs` value of `cutdirsmapper` depending on the location of your files.

```
<target name="default">
    <delete dir="Folder1" />
    <delete dir="Folder2" />

    <mkdir dir="Folder1" />
    <touch file="Folder1/Package1" />
    <touch file="Folder1/Package2" />

    <mkdir dir="Folder2" />
    <touch file="Folder2/Package1" />
    <touch file="Folder2/Package2" />

    <pathconvert property="packages" pathsep="${line.separator}" dirsep=".">
        <fileset dir="." includes="Folder1/**/*,Folder2/**/*" id="packages" />
        <cutdirsmapper dirs="4" />
    </pathconvert>

    <echo message="${packages}" />
</target>
```